# How to use an implication backwards?

Tags: calculus, logic

I have started Calculus by Spivak, and there is an excercise which hints the use of a property proved earlier, saying to use that property, which is an implication, backwards.

The property proved earlier is:

If $0 \leq a \lt b$, then $a^2 \lt b^2$

The property to prove (using the previos statement backwards) is:

If $a, b \geq 0$ and $a^2 \lt b^2$, then $a \lt b$

I don't know how to use an implication backwards. If I assume the conclusion (of the implication) is true, the implication does not guarantee that the premise is also true.

Comment: You can't really use the first implication directly. You can probably adapt the _proof_ of the implication without too much work, though.

Comment: You can start by assuming $b<a$. Then, by the previous property you would have $b^2<a^2$. This contradicts $a^2<b^2$. Therefore, the assumption is false. Namely $b\not<a$. Therefore, $a\leq b$. Now, if $a=b$ then $a^2=b^2$, which also contradicts that $a^2<b^2$. Therefore $a=b$ is also false. Hence $a<b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the book instructs you to "use the previous statement backwards," I think it's instructing you to use what's called a direct proof, sometimes known as a conditional proof. In a direct proof of some statement $p \to q$, you begin by assuming the antecedent, $p$, and then validly deducing the consequent $q$.

The previous statement was $(0 \le a \lt b) \to (a^2 \lt b^2)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. "Using it backwards" suggests that you should assume $a^2 \lt b^2$ and then validly deduce $0 \le a \lt b$. Of course, this is not necessarily true, and the statement you are supposed to be proving is slightly different. You are trying to prove $(a,b \ge 0) \wedge (a^2 \lt b^2) \to (a \lt b)$. So here's what I think you should do...

Use the direct proof in which you assume $(a,b \ge 0) \wedge (a^2 \lt b^2)$ and then validly deduce $a \lt b$. I believe this is the gist of what they meant by telling you to "use the previous statement backwards," albeit their instructions could have been worded much better.